# Getting TimeoutException on sending Informs via SharpSNMPLib

Tags: c#, sharp-snmp

I am using SharpSNMPLib on C# to send Informs but always getting a timeoutException. This is apparently caused by the lack of reply as stated on the documentation [here](http://sharpsnmplib4.rssing.com/chan-7081518/all_p8.html) :

```
Messenger.SendInform(0, 
                     VersionCode.V2, 
                     new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("192.168.1.3"), 162), 
                     new OctetString("public"), 
                     new ObjectIdentifier("1.3.6.1.2.1.1"), 
                     0, 
                     new List<Variable>(), 
                     2000, 
                     null, 
                     null);
```

> The manager should send back a reply to this INFORM message.
>   Otherwise, a TimeoutException occurs.

Does anyone know how to send back a reply in order to avoid this exception?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answered offline, but paste the answer here for future reference.

The code base contains an snmptrapd sample, which illustrated how to construct a manager pipeline,

https://github.com/lextm/sharpsnmplib/blob/master/Samples/CSharp/snmptrapd/Program.cs

It is such a pipeline that handles incoming TRAP and INFORM messages and replies in a proper way.

You might further read the checkout steps to see how the test agent and snmptrapd should work together,

http://docs.sharpsnmp.com/en/latest/samples/command-line-tools.html#checkout

When an INFORM message is sent from the test agent after the button is clicked, the snmptrapd program will reply to it and log to console.